# How do I use Redis in Ruby on Rails to take the dot product of two hashes efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, redis, dot-product

I have a data structure like this in the database in the features table called `token_vector` (a hash):

```
Feature.find(1).token_vector = { "a" => 0.1, "b" => 0.2, "c" => 0.3 }
```

There are 25 of these features. First, I entered the data into Redis with this in `script/console`:

```
REDIS.set(  "feature1",
            "#{ TokenVector.to_json Feature.find(1).token_vector }"
)
# ...
REDIS.set(  "feature25",
            "#{ TokenVector.to_json Feature.find(25).token_vector }"
)
```

`TokenVector.to_json` converts the hash into JSON format first. The 25 JSON hashes stored in Redis take up about 8 MB.

I have a method, called `Analysis#locate`. This method takes the dot product between two token_vectors. The dot product for hashes works like this:

```
hash1 = { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 }
hash2 = { "a" => 4, "b" => 5, "c" => 6, "d" => 7 }
```

Each overlapping key in the hash (a, b, and c in this case, and not d) have their values multiplied pairwise together, then added up.

The value for `a` in `hash1` is 1, the value for `a` in `hash2` is 4. Multiply these to get `1*4 = 4`.

The value for `b` in `hash1` is 2, the value for `b` in `hash2` is 5. Multiply these to get `2*5 = 10`.

The value for `c` in `hash1` is 3, the value for `c` in `hash2` is 6. Multiply these to get `3*6 = 18`.

The value for `d` in `hash1` is nonexistent, the value for `d` in `hash2` is 7. In this case, set `d = 0` for the first hash. Multiply these to get `0*7 = 0`.

Now add up the multiplied values. `4 + 10 + 18 + 0 = 32`. This is the dot product of hash1 and hash2.

```
Analysis.locate( hash1, hash2 ) # => 32
```

I have a method that is often used, `Analysis#topicize`. This method takes in a parameter, `token_vector`, which is just a hash, similar to above. `Analysis#topicize` takes the dot product of `token_vector` and each of the 25 features' `token_vectors`, and creates a new vector of those 25 dot products, called `feature_vector`. A `feature_vector` is just an array. Here is what the code looks like:

```
def self.topicize token_vector

  feature_vector = FeatureVector.new

  feature_vector.push(
    locate( token_vector, TokenVector.from_json( REDIS.get "feature1" ) )
  )
  # ...
  feature_vector.push(
    locate( token_vector, TokenVector.from_json( REDIS.get "feature25" ) )
  )

  feature_vector

end
```

As you can see, it takes the dot product of `token_vector` and each feature's `token_vector` that I entered into Redis above, and pushes the value into an array.

My problem is, this takes about 18 seconds each time I invoke the method. Am I misusing Redis? I think the problem could be that I shouldn't load Redis data into Ruby. Am I supposed to send Redis the data (`token_vector`) and write a Redis function to have it do the `dot_product` function, rather than writing it with Ruby code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to profile it to be sure, but I suspect you're losing a lot of time in serializing/deserializing JSON objects. Instead of turning `token_vector` into a JSON string, why not put it directly into Redis, since Redis has [its own hash type](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes)?

```
REDIS.hmset "feature1",   *Feature.find(1).token_vector.flatten
# ...
REDIS.hmset "feature25",  *Feature.find(25).token_vector.flatten
```

What `Hash#flatten` does is turns a hash like `{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }` into an array like `[ 'a', 1, 'b', 2 ]`, and then we use splat (`*`) to send each element of the array as an argument to `Redis#hmset` (the "m" in "hmset" is for "multiple," as in "set multiple hash values at once").

Then when you want to get it back out use `Redis#hgetall`, which automatically returns a Ruby Hash:

```
def self.topicize token_vector
  feature_vector = FeatureVector.new

  feature_vector.push locate( token_vector, REDIS.hgetall "feature1" )
  # ...
  feature_vector.push locate( token_vector, REDIS.hgetall "feature25" )

  feature_vector
end
```

However! Since you only care about the values, and not the keys, from the hash, you can streamline things a little more by using `Redis#hvals`, which just returns an array of the values, instead of `hgetall`.

The second place you might be spending a lot of cycles is in `locate`, which you haven't provided the source for, but there are a lot of ways to write a dot product method in Ruby and some of them are more performant than others. [This ruby-talk thread](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes) covers some valuable ground. One of the posters points to [NArray](http://narray.rubyforge.org/), a library that implements numeric arrays and vectors in C.

If I understand your code correctly it could be reimplemented something like this (prereq: `gem install narray`):

```
require 'narray'

def self.topicize token_vector
  # Make sure token_vector is an NVector
  token_vector  = NVector.to_na token_vector unless token_vector.is_a? NVector
  num_feats     = 25

  # Use Redis#multi to bundle every operation into one call.
  # It will return an array of all 25 features' token_vectors.
  feat_token_vecs = REDIS.multi do
    num_feats.times do |feat_idx|
      REDIS.hvals "feature#{feat_idx + 1}"
    end
  end 

  pad_to_len = token_vector.length

  # Get the dot product of each of those arrays with token_vector
  feat_token_vecs.map do |feat_vec|
    # Make sure the array is long enough by padding it out with zeroes (using
    # pad_arr, defined below). (Since Redis only returns strings we have to
    # convert each value with String#to_f first.)
    feat_vec = pad_arr feat_vec.map(&:to_f), pad_to_len

    # Then convert it to an NVector and do the dot product
    token_vector * NVector.to_na(feat_vec)

    # If we need to get a Ruby Array out instead of an NVector use #to_a, e.g.:
    # ( token_vector * NVector.to_na(feat_vec) ).to_a
  end
end

# Utility to pad out array with zeroes to desired size
def pad_arr arr, size
  arr.length < size ?
    arr + Array.new(size - arr.length, 0) : arr
end
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: It looks like I am running into a problem in `feature_vector.push( locate( token_vector, REDIS.hgetall( "feature1" ) ) )`. `token_vector` is of class `TokenVector`, and `REDIS.hgetall( "feature1" )` is of class `Hash`. I need `REDIS.hgetall( "feature1" )` to be of class `TokenVector`. `TokenVector` is actually a subclass of `Hash`, just with some more methods. How do I change the class of `REDIS.hgetall( "feature1" )` from `Hash` to `TokenVector`?

Comment: In short: `locate( token_vector, TokenVector[ REDIS.hgetall "feature1" ] )`. Since TokenVector is a subclass of Hash it inherits Hash's class method `[]` which can take as an argument a Hash. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.src/M000716.html

Comment: I actually posted an answer, but it is really a follow up to my previous comment. Can you take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, just a follow up to my previous comment, since this probably won't fit into a comment. It looks like the Hash/TokenVector issue might not have been the only problem. I do:

```
token_vector = Feature.find(1).token_vector
Analysis.locate( token_vector, TokenVector[ REDIS.hgetall( "feature1" ) ] )
```

and get this error:

```
TypeError: String can't be coerced into Float
from /Users/RedApple/S/lib/analysis/vectors.rb:26:in `*'
from /Users/RedApple/S/lib/analysis/vectors.rb:26:in `block in dot'
from /Users/RedApple/S/lib/analysis/vectors.rb:24:in `each'
from /Users/RedApple/S/lib/analysis/vectors.rb:24:in `inject'
from /Users/RedApple/S/lib/analysis/vectors.rb:24:in `dot'
from /Users/RedApple/S/lib/analysis/analysis.rb:223:in `locate'
from (irb):6
from /Users/RedApple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Analysis#locate looks like this:

```
def self.locate vector1, vector2
  vector1.dot vector2
end
```

Here is the relevant part of analysis/vectors.rb lines 23-28, the TokenVector#dot method:

```
def dot vector
  inject 0 do |product,item|
    axis, value = item
    product + value * ( vector[axis] || 0 )
  end
end
```

I am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Oh, my bad. The Redis gem only returns strings, so you'll have to convert each value to a number first. With a Hash you can't just do `map &:to_f` alas--but e.g. `(hsh = REDIS.hgetall(...)).merge(hsh) {|key,val| val.to_f }` should do the trick. If you wanted you could override `TokenVector.[]` to do this *in situ*.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that worked. I wish I could give you 5 points for your answer.

Comment: Great! Did you get any speed increase out of it?

Comment: It went from 18 seconds to less than 1 second to run `Analysis.topicize( token_vector )`.